# How to view Office files in Primefaces?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to create a component to view **pdf,office files and images**
and i was wondering if it's possible to customize primefaces media component to view images and office files, if that's not possible then please suggest me the appropriate way to do that.

Comment: Did you see [p:lightbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf)? And why don't you just use `p:graphicImage`?

Comment: @Ömer Faruk Almalı, how to use it to display office files ?

Comment: @Ömer Faruk Almalı users are going to upload different types of files, and each files will have a link, and when clicking on the link the file should be displayed in the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<p:lightBox>  
    <h:outputLink value="#">  
        <h:outputText value="Click Here"/>  
    </h:outputLink>  

    <f:facet name="inline">  
       <p:media value="/resources/other/guide.pdf" width="100%" height="300px">  
           <h:outputLink value="/resources/other/guide.pdf"></h:outputLink> 
       </p:media> 
    </f:facet>  
</p:lightBox>
```

That generates a link which user can see the media content. If you want to do this user-specific, you should give user-specific named folders maybe and the link value is going to contain that like:

```
<p:media value="/user1/pdf/1.pdf"/>
```

Since `p:lightBox` has `iframe` property which means you can embed html code into `p:lightBox`. So that should work inside `p:lightBox`:

```
<iframe src="file1.xls"></iframe>
```

Also you can try to use embedding Google documents:

- [How to](https://docs.google.com/viewer)
- [Example](http://sitesguide.pjrprojects.co.uk/google-sites/how-tos/embed-an-iframe/editable-google-doc)

About:

- [p:media](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf)
- [p:lightBox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf)

An alternative:

- [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
- [With PDF files](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: still didn't answer my main question, is this can be customized for office files ?

Comment: @Ömer I just found this answer, but is really really old, and some links doesnt work. Is there an updated answer ?